# HTML Powered Navigation in a PPT

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, html

**Premise:**

I want a navigation bar in a PPT so that you can access different segments of the presentation with an easy click. This can be done with no fancy coding, but it requires adding a ton of hyperlinks to images, and the images can be hard to align properly in addition to an overall increase in the likelihood user error.

**What I want to do:**

Instead, I would like to use the html language to create easy to re-use navigation buttons to access different slides (in addition to other cool, on-hover effects and other style rules).

**One way I know:**

There is a PPT plug-in called live web that lets you embed a html page to a PPT slide. Which is really cool, but drawbacks are many: its antiquated (10+ years old), only supports internet explorer (resulting in a ton of security errors), can't interface with other slides that easily.

**What I would like to ask the community:**

Is there a way to create html navigation without so much fuss? Or would I be better off just presenting from a website instead of using powerpoint?

I'm using MS Office 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint wouldn't know what to do with your HTML navigation code, so that won't help. Whether 'tis nobler to switch to HTML or stick with PPT is up to you and the needs of your presentation.

However, depending on what you need to do, adding navigation links on the slide master or layout(s) might be sufficient and would be much easier to maintain than a set of links on each slide.

Google PowerPoint navigation bar for a lot of tips/ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Got tons of hyperlinks?  I suggest just ditching PowerPoint, and go with an HTML-based solution.  Check out:

- [Slidy](http://cyberpillar.com/dirsver/1/mainsite/software/office/showsoft/showsoft.htm#slidy)
- and variations/successors:

  - [XSLidy Slide #5](http://dret.net/projects/xslidy/latest/intro#%285%29)
  - [S<sup>5</sup>](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/s5-intro.html)

Getting the slideshow effect is pretty easy to implement once you have the files and figured out how to do it once (or have a guide to demonstrate how).

As for a navigation bar, I'm thinking that's kind of a separate topic (more about HTML navigation, less about having a PowerPoint-like slide show), and I felt like you mentioned it in a rather broad way.  If you have specific questions, please elaborate (ideally in separate SuperUser questions if they are sufficiently unique and specific).